# ReactJS + NodeJS: What is error "Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I transferred a ReactJS + NodeJS project from another computer to a new computer. Then inside the folder, I did `npm install` in the terminal but getting the following response back.

```
> fsevents@1.0.14 install /Users/Joshua/Projects/practice_project/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/Joshua/Projects/practice_project/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
```

And on the previous computer, I ran the project via `npm run server`, but when I do it after `npm run server` in the project on the new computer, now I am getting:

```
> practice_project@1.0.0 serve /Users/Joshua/Projects/practice_project
> nodemon server/server.js --ignore components

sh: nodemon: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
npm ERR! node v4.6.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! practice_project@1.0.0 serve: `nodemon server/server.js --ignore components`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

I looked around but can't seem to find the right solution. Tried `npm install -g node-gyp` but getting `tar.unpack untar error`.

What could be the issue? Will upvote and accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: So the first message isn't an error, it's just telling you it tried to rebuild the binary, but found that it didn't need to (it was already built).  The second implies that you do not have `nodemon` installed.  On your other computer it was probably installed globally and you forgot to install it on the new machine.

Comment: @DaveV Got it. For a learning purpose, what does rebuilding in binary mean? And I tried `npm install -g nodemon`, but getting an error: `npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/jchoi/.npm/nodemon/1.11.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "nodemon"
npm ERR! node v4.6.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir`

Comment: Some of the packages are rebuilt based on your environment (OS, bitness, etc) every time you pull them.  That new message looks like a permission issue installing packages global.  I'm not great with Linux so the best I can tell you is probably bad advice, run the install with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the first message you received is just telling you it's attempting to rebuild the `fsevents` package for your environment, then realized it already had it built, so stopped the process.

The second message is indicating that you are attempting to run `nodemon` but it isn't installed.  I would hazard a guess that it was installed globally on your previous machine (and therefore not included in the project's `package.json`).  If you want to install it globally again, you'll need to run `npm i -g nodemon`.